# Used Michelin tires safe to install?

Tags: tires, safety, wear

My Michelin set of 4, set inside a vehicle 4 years; there are NO VISIBLE CRACKS WHATSOEVER and GREAT THREAD DEPTH REMAINS ALMOST LIKE NEW!!!!! My concern is I KNOW NOTHING ABOUT TIRE SAFETY and NEED SOME INFORMATION.

I am disabled now, trying to save money IF THESE "TUCKED AWAY" TIRES are SAFE TO INSTALL it would greatly help me under financial constraints. BUT IF THERE IS REAL DANGER IN ATTEPTING TO INSTALL THAN DRIVE ON TIRES WHICH SET 4 YEARS, I NEED TO AVOID THAT RISK! Please don't give me "spook tales", or "wives tales".... Facts only please.

Opinions are fine too just clarify for me that it is opinion.
Facts are real component to safety, surely some people know this one!

Her are some factors which may impact this serious question:
The vehicle was outdoors, not garaged.
The 4 Michelin tires were set inside it.
Yes, sun was on the tires somewhat.... 
And of course exposed to heat locked in vehicle closed up to elements.

Would a tire shop know??
If looked over tires??????
What about a used tire shop too?

Please lend me your insight.
Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your question correctly, the set of tires is 4 years old. A recommendation I have heard is to never install 6 year old tires, and if the tires are 10 years old and still being used, they should be removed from service. The reason for this is that rubber has a tendency to degrade with age. Of course, when installing old tires, you should obviously inspect the tires for damage and tread depth. In your question you have already said that, so you're good to go.

I have driven on over 20 year old Nokian Hakkapeliitta studded winter tires. The traction was awful. But, on the other hand, it taught me a thing or two about winter driving. I would not recommend using over 10 year old tires, however. Actually, I have experienced also that 8 year old studded winter tires that had still plenty of tread depth had poor traction on hard snow. On the other hand, I got rid of my 2011 Toyota Yaris when it was about 5.5 years old, and I didn't observe catastrophically reduced traction. So, if you want maximum traction, the point at which you should change your tires is between 5.5 years and 8 years.

Answer (score 2):

Two things:

1. Tire rubber degradation is largely (but not exclusively) a mixture of UV light ("sunlight"), weight one them (from the car) and temperature/moisture. The storage conditions you described are less than ideal, but probably no worse than having the tires actual installed on a car.
2. As a rule-of-thumb, rubber tires have a 6 year life. Yours are 4 years old, then again one of my sets of summer tires is 8 years old. Mine are just about worn out now, from mileage though, not from age.

Your tires are probably fine. If you want to poke around, check their pressure (your question doesn't say, but I assume they are mounted on wheels). They are probably running a bit low after 4 years, so pump them up to the needed pressure (see the sticker inside your driver door), and check them after a week. If they are still at the exact same pressure, they are holding air and are most likely fine. Check them again after a month.